# Spring Boot @Async is called Synchronously

Tags: spring, asynchronous, spring-boot

I have a long running service method which I'm starting with a rest call from the controller.

Service:

```
@Service
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("1: " + DateTime.now());
        runLongTask();
        System.out.println("2: " + DateTime.now());

    }

    @Async
    private runLongTask() {
        System.out.println("Test");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("3: "+ DateTime.now());
    }
}
```

In my Application.java I have

```
private int poolSize = 10;

private int queueCapacity = 10;

@Bean(name="taskExecutor")
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(this.poolSize);
    taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(this.queueCapacity);
    taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
    return new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
}
```

And of course I have the @EnableAsync Annotation at my Application.java class

So I would Expect that the output is something like that:

```
1: 2015-10-23 11:20:00
2: 2015-10-23 11:20:01
Test
3: 2015-10-23 11:20:11
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you need to call method from different class to use annotations like `@Async` or `@Transactional`. Spring do this stuff by wrapping annotated methods by proxy. In case when you call method from the same class then it has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html) you need to implement the `AsyncConfigurer` interface in your `Configuration` class (in this case I assume is your `Application` instance) to override the `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`.

A full example is also shown in the documentation:

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableAsync
 public class AppConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

 @Bean
 public MyAsyncBean asyncBean() {
     return new MyAsyncBean();
 }

 @Override
 public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
     ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
     executor.setCorePoolSize(7);
     executor.setMaxPoolSize(42);
     executor.setQueueCapacity(11);
     executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MyExecutor-");
     executor.initialize();
     return executor;
 }

 @Override
 public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
         return MyAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler();
 }
}
```

HTH,

Jose Luis